# Which interrupt number in the IDT represents the RTC interrupt

Tags: windows, 64-bit, windbg

I'm using WinDbg to dump the contents of the IDT and I would like to know which interrupt number represents the Real Time Clock Interrupt in this table of things ? I've ran the **!idt -a** command to dump the contents of the IDT in Windbg.But cannot tell which row belongs to the RTC interrupt.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to Provide a bit more Detailed information on what you have done and where you are stuck
As is Your Query will not attract clear answers

for starters have you dumped the the Interrupt Descriptor tables
using the provided bang command **!idt with its arguments** and not satisficed with the results ?

```
0: kd> .shell -ci "!idt" grep -i clock
<.shell waiting 10 second(s) for process>
d1:     fffff8033cf51908 hal!HalpTimerClockInterrupt (KINTERRUPT fffff8033d725100)
d2:     fffff8033cf51910 hal!HalpTimerClockIpiRoutine (KINTERRUPT fffff8033d725000)
.shell: Process exited
0: kd>
```

have you looked at !timer command does it provide what you are looking for ?

```
0: kd> !timer
Dump system timers

Interrupt time: 26a78346 00000515 [11/27/2021 12:49:47.524]

List Timer    Interrupt Low/High     Fire Time              DPC/thread
PROCESSOR 0 (nt!_KTIMER_TABLE fffff80339a7a800)
  0 ffffc388b8805180    27d3e28b 00000515 [11/27/2021 12:49:49.493]  thread ffffc388b8805080
```

you should also be aware on the newer os these are shadows due to the ongoing security hardening of operating systems.

Comment: Hello @blabb. I am trying to locate (visually) the address of the RTC Interrupt (using the !idt command) in Windbg but do not know which interrupt it is. No I have not tried the !timer command. Can you describe a little more as to what the meaning of the results from running the !timer command ? My ultimate goal is to write C code to dump the contents of the RTC interrupt to a text file. Thanks.